# Counting such 3-digit numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Count the number of 3-digit natural numbers N with the property that the sum of the digits of N is divisible by the product of the digits of N.

Let abc be the number
then
(abc)k = a + b + c

k= 1/bc+ 1/ac+ 1/ab

k is required to be a natural number for this to hold true

How do I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: 1. None of the digits can be $0$. 2. Let $d$ be the largest of the digits. Then $a + b + c \leqslant 3d$, so the product of the other two digits is $\leqslant 3$, hence at least one of the digits is $1$. And $d$ divides the sum of the other two digits. If that sum is $2d$, i.e. all three digits are equal, we get $d^3 \mid 3d$, whence $d^2 \mid 3$, so $d = 1$. Otherwise, the sum of the two smaller digits is $d$, so the smaller digits are $1$ and $d-1$. Then we get $d(d-1) \mid 2d$, i.e. $(d-1)\mid 2$.

Answer (score 0):

So, we know that $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$(a+b+c) = k\cdot abc$$ and $$a\neq0$$Note that when $b,c = 0$, this holds since $abc=0$. Other than that, there isn't much more you can do than smart counting for this problem.

Comment: Note: For the sum to be divisible by the product, you want $a+b+c=kabc$ for some integer $k$.